# php как достать последнии символы

Tags: php

Проблема заключается в том что в страке находятся множество точек и нужно получить символы после ПОСЛЕДНЕЙ ТОЧКИ!
Пример:
abc.xvds.xcsdfxcvxcv_sdfsdsd.cxvsdxcv.sdfxcvxc.ras
в этом случае мне нужно .ras
то есть получение последней точки и символы правее нее!

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php. У вас в слове "страке" ошибка, быть может вы имели ввиду "сраке" или "строке"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Преобразуем строку в массив и выводим последние значение из массива

```
$text = "nu.tut.tipa.text";

$last = explode('.', $text);
var_dump($last[count($last) - 1]);
```